# android httpurlconenction request method 405 not allowed

Tags: android, http

Responsecode returns 405 to me, i dont understand where is the error in my applied code? I am using httpurlconnection to connect to the internet.

> ```
>         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
>                 conn.setReadTimeout(60000);
>                 conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
>                 conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
>                 conn.setDoInput(true);
>                 conn.setDoOutput(true);
>                 conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
>                 String sessionId = "JSESSIONID=" + Common.getAuthCode();
>                 conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionId);
>                 conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",System.getProperty("http.agent"));
>                 OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
>                 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
>                         new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));                   
>                 writer.write(getQuery(params));
>                 writer.flush();
>                 writer.close();
>                 os.close();
>                 conn.connect();
>                 int status = conn.getResponseCode();
>                 System.out.println("statue "+status);
>                 switch (status) {
>                     case 200:
>                     case 201:
>                         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
>                         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>                         String line;
>                         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>                             sb.append(line+"\n");
>                         }
>                         br.close();
>                         System.out.println("here");
>                         return sb.toString();
>                 }
> ```

Comment: is it add header not working? am using setRequestProperty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **GET** request, remove `conn.setDoOutput(true);` line. However, I think this should be **POST** request. Replace `conn.setRequestMethod("GET");`
 by `conn.setRequestMethod("POST");` then run your app again.